# download large zip files (around 50mb) using node js

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I want to download large zip file having size around 50 mb using node js. I have tried http.get and I also tried "dld" plugin for file download but not working. Please tell me some way or any plugin which will be useful to solve this download issue. 
I am developing this app in node-webkit. My code is working fine for small zip files.
http.get method is working only for small files.

Comment: could you please submit an issue on github with your sample?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use fs: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html and write the file to disc. So first http.get the file and write it using fs.writeFile().

fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node', function (err) { if (err) throw err; console.log('It\'s saved!'); });

(on mobile,  excuse me for my brewity)

Comment: I want to download file from internet.